# UL list grid stacking oddly

Tags: html, css, grid, html-lists

I'm getting ready to launch a new site for a client today. I didn't see any previous posts that really covered the issue I'm having.

The staged site: http://honeststudio.com/lecture-videos/

Basically, I have a grid of YouTube videos in an unordered list. This morning as the client was adding videos a big space opened up in the grid before the "Warren Carther Lecture Part 2" video (second last row, very right). I haven't really seen a CSS styled list behave this way before.

When I removed the left float on the list items, it cleaned up the grid, but the "Warren Carther Lecture Part 1" (second row down, very right) sat 20px from the top of the row.

I've done a lot of trial and error the past half hour and haven't made a lot of progress, so any help would be really awesome!

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `clear` somewhere? That seems like a reason for the space to open up when adding a video. Or, try making is `display:inline-block` instead of using the `float:left` and see what happens?

Comment: I ended up adding a fixed height to the li items and it fixed it all up. While not ideal, it is workable. The problem existed in Firefox latest.